# Writing an AtmelStudio 7 plugin

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, atmelstudio

I would like to make a plug-in for AtmelStudio 7 (in C# or C++). But I have no idea where to start. While it was quite easy to find guides for Eclipse plug-in development, I'm having troubles to find a good guide for AtmelStudio plug-in development.

The official site from Atmel hosts an old version mentioning only an old version (v6.1).

I also opened a ticket about this at Atmel, but no body answered.

Some hints where to start would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket an Atmel's bugtracker about this issue. They told me that Atmel does currently not working on an update of the documents and gave me the following hints to start writing a plugin:

- In Atmel AVR10006: XDK – User Guide, user need to use/install Atmel Studio 7.0.
- Install Atmel Studio IDE SDK for Atmel Studio 7 from the [gallery](http://distribute.atmel.no/tools/AS7/as6-sdk-installer-trunk-7.0.387-win32.win32.x86.exe)
- Atmel studio 7 uses Visual Studio 2015, this has to be taken care as well.
- Where ever the user need to select the IDE/SDK version, user should select Atmel Studio/SDK 7.0
- GUI appearance may be slightly different from the screenshots available in the user guide.